# Is it Possible to see pine script TradingView created?

Tags: pine-script

I was wondering if you can see pine scripts TradingView created such as “pivots” like others?

Scrips someone made can be seen but not TradingView original.

I like to refer to it to make my scripts since I’m new to pine.

Comment: The scripts from the community are listed under "community scripts" when you search for a script. Everything else is from TradingView.

Answer (score 0):

Not every indicator published by Tradingview is open source.

You can check if it is available after you add it to your chart as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But unfortunately it doesn’t show it thus  I cannot see inside the cord….

Comment: Then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: I found the cord I can access It can go from ••• option very right side of the the menu!!! Thank you for your hint!!! Thank you!!!!